# Configuring a sidebar_action to be only on for certain sites?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-sidebar

I want to create a firefox extension that allows a sidebar to automatically show when a user navigates to certain web pages.

For example, let's say I configure it so if a user navigates to `google.com` they will be presented a sidebar that lets them see some "previous searches" they had done.

I do not want them to have to click a menu action / keyboard shortcut to display it. And I do not want to display it indefinitely.

I've been looking at these links to learn how to use sidebars:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Sidebars

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/sidebar_action

https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/annotate-page

But they do not seem to cover how to hide/show sidebars conditionally. They are just kinda, always shown. Not really what I want.

Is there a way to use sidebars in this way or should I use another method?

Comment: Which event will cause said sidebar to appear, and which events causes it to be hidden?

Comment: page navigation only. in my example, if they have navigated to `google.com` the sidebar appears. otherwise, it disappears. or perhaps, if the URL they have visited matches a regex such as `.*\/event\/.*`

Comment: so, as long as the user is on google.com, the side bar should be visible, and as soon as he/she visits another domain, the sidebar should go away. Is that right?

Comment: yep. i think in my real use case, it will be whenever a user navigates to a page who's url matches a regex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control when your extension is inserted into the currently visited page (thus, causing your sidebar to appear) or not based on the permission settings in the manifest file

## manifest.json

```
...
"permissions": [
  ... 
  "http://*.google.com/",
  "http://*event*/",
  ...
],
```

In the above example, the extension will work only on google.com as well as any domain containing the word `event`. If you want to target domains where the word `event` appear as part of the path, then you would use something like

```
"http://*/*event*/*",
```

You get the idea.

For more information read [Google's Extension Development - Declare Permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions)

Comment: tried it. it didn't work on firefox. i haven't tried chrome, but i'm not making an extension for chrome. `"permissions": ["storage",
     "tabs",
     "http://*.google.com/*"
  ],`

Comment: hi @ahmad i added a bounty. any chance you could try out the firefox sidebar extension example in firefox and see if you can find a solution that works? what you posted here doesn't work for me

Comment: I’ll give it a try @NicholasDiPiazza

Comment: Cool! Thanks! Much appreciated

Comment: i'll just give your answer credit because it does work in chrome.

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza sorry I couldn’t be of more help, and thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by specifying hosts which can be either one of a list of known strings (such as "geolocation") or a match pattern that gives access to one or more hosts.

Here's an example of the permissions part of a manifest file:

```
"permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "http://www.blogger.com/",
  "http://*.google.com/",
  "unlimitedStorage"
],
```